# Send file reload signal from command line to java application (tracker)

Tags: java, linux

[Tracker](https://physlets.org/tracker/) a video analysis and physics modelling software written in Java uses simple xml (=trk) files for saving files (in particular data of models). So it is possible just to edit the xml file, save it, close and reopen the file inside tracker to see the changes.

However this is a bit annoying and slow, so I am looking for a way that an opened file loads the changes automatically after saving the edited xml file.

So it there a generic way to send a "data reload" signal or something like that from linux command line (maybe if I run the jar file with specific command line parameters).

Comment: That would have to be supported by the application. Since it claims to be open source, if it doesn't, you might be able to implement it using [one of these](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.